# C# reflection cast to variable type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Just started studying reflection and im having a lot of issues. I want to cast to find the type of properties and then set them. So i wanted to cast to these properties type.

```
protected override object Load(SqlDataReader dr)
        {
            object item = Activator.CreateInstance(klass);



            foreach (var p in klass.GetProperties())
            {
                MethodInfo pSet = p.GetSetMethod();
                Type pType= p.PropertyType;
                object setParam = dr[p.Name]; 
                object[] paramArray = (object[])Array.CreateInstance(pType, 1);
                paramArray[0] = setParam;
                pSet.Invoke(item, paramArray);
            }
            return item;
        }
```

Comment: You really should include the errors that you are getting or what results you get and what you expect to get.  Also where does `klass` come from?  Is it a `Type` variable or just the actual name of the class?

Comment: This looks like another attempt at reinventing Dapper, which is fine if you're doing it for educational purposes, but not a hot idea if you want to use it for production code. (For starters, this approach is terribly slow, relatively speaking.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they said you need to add your errors, but from what i see you have two problems:

You use `klass` as Type instead of `typeof(klass)`
You try to cast a whole array to a new type - this can be solved using `Array.ConvertAll`... but the easier way would be to just initialize a regular array using: `object[] paramArray = new object[1]`.

good luck

Comment: New to c# and reflection as this is for college. The class has a property of the type Type named klass

Comment: So again, please add more code and errors. Anyway, did you try changing the casting as i suggested?